# Sorting array items by frequency value

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, key-value, frequency

is there a good way or algorithm to sort an array by the value of a frequency in each item? Let's say I have this array:
[3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 12, 5, 5, 6]. I want the output to be [3, 5, 6, 12]. I was thinking about something like insertionsort but I belive that there could be an easier way.

Comment: sort by histogram however that is not frequency !!! if you want sort by frequency then you first need to compute the frequency (count oscillations of number so `3,3,3` is the same as `3` but `3,?,3` is not unless you handle `3,3` as max frequency) in such case the output would be `5,6 ; 3,12` instead of your current `3; 5; 6; 12`. So which one it is ... if first please repair the title if the second repair your example and clarify what frequency you want to sort by (mean,avg,max,min ?) as its not constant in your sample.

Comment: I made an updated post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67414015/sorting-keys-in-array-by-frequency-value-in-java. I belive that I explain it better there.

Comment: 1. please do not post duplicate questions instead edit the new info into your original one. 2. so by frequency you mean occurrence (that is not frequency ... frequency has very different meaning? 3. So You want to sort 2 tight together values by only one of them ... so construct **histogram** for your array and **index sort** it then print the indexes in sorted order

Comment: I think ive got the idea now.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you definetly need the count for each element, which is O(n). Then you can make a unique list from it (let's say it has m elements), and sort it according to the frequency with any sorting algo, you like. It will be O(n+mlog(m)).
For example in python:

```
from collections import Counter

myList = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c']

myCounter = Counter(myList)
myUniqueList = list(myCounter)
sorted(myUniqueList, key=lambda e: myCounter[e])
```

Editted according to Paddy3118 's comment

Comment: You could substitute `myUniqueList = list(myCounter)` as the Counter keys are unique, but your way works too :-)

Comment: Nice one! I added it to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

First you count them

```
std::unordered_map<int, int> dict;
for(auto &val : array)
   dict[val]++; // O(N)
```

Then you sort them

```
std::vector vec(dict.begin(), dict.end());
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](auto a, auto b) { return a.second > b.second }); // O(M lg M), requires C++14 to use auto
```